# How do I unconditionally disable all the "smart" terminal actions in vim

Tags: terminal, x11, ssh

I have already `set mouse=` and `set ttymouse=` but I still get it intercepting paste when I'm trying to paste vim commands, like I want it to do some kind of complex `:map! ....` so I copy that from another window and paste it in vim, and instead of having it execute the command it inserts the text at mouse pointer position.

It also pastes the text at the mouse pointer position instead of at the cursor position.

I don't want vim interacting with X11 at all, I want it to act like any other text mode program running in a terminal window or over ssh.

Running: vim 8.1 on Raspberry pi.

Comment: How you trigger paste? Also, if you're trying to execute a `:[mode][nore]map` (really do try to prefer these targeted, non-recursive variants), why not type it out? Or paste it in vimscript file and source it?

Comment: Right click and select paste from the Terminal menu. Drag and drop from another window. It seems pretty consistent.

Why not type it out or use other workaround like sourcing a file?

I've been using this kind of workflow on vi and clones since maybe the mid '80s when I started using multi-window interfaces locally and with telnet or later ssh access to systems running UNIX. I don't see this as a particularly onerous request.

I normally replace vim with nvi to avoid these kinds of dubious shenanigans, but on the Pi I'm trying to stick to the standard load-out as much as possible.